# Remove focus from an input field in a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button onclick of which a jquery dialog appears with two input fields which are jquery datepickers. Whenever the dialog appears, the first fields gets focus automatically, hence the datepicker pops up. I have resolved this for now by adding another dummy input field. Is there a better way ?

Sorry if the question is repeated. I tried searching for one already existing but couldn't get one. Please point me to an existing question if present.

Edit:

Okay my code goes as follows. onClick of a button the jdialog appears and there are 2 datepicker input fields inside the div "select_date_dialog".

```
$("#select_date").click(function(){
    $("#select_date_dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'connect-dialog',
        height: 100,
        width: 500
    });
});
```

afaik: can you be a bit more specific how blur will help me ? I tried adding this as suggested.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
                $('#custom_from_date').blur();
            }
```

blur happens when there input field loses focus. can i use blur to specify whether that field should get focus or not ?

Comment: have you tried the blur() method?

Comment: yes, I am posting my code in an edit with some comments.

Comment: try this instead: `$('input').blur();` maybe the ID of the actual text box is not custom_from_date so you better play it safe.

Comment: @alokswain please show us the HTML/ASPX code of the dialog window.

Comment: The html code for the dialog window: 

<div id="select_date_dialog" title="Custom date range" style="display: none;">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  FROM
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="text" id="custom_from_date" name="custom_from_date" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  TO
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="text" id="custom_to_date" name="custom_from_date" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='button' id="custom_date_submit" class='fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-corner-right' value='<%=I18n.t 'connect.chart_section.ok' %>'/>
</div>

Comment: @alokswain - the `$('input').blur();` works just fine, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CsDEe/ so it means you did something wrong.

Comment: Feel free to add more code to the jsfiddle to show what's happening if it's still not working.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for the jsfiddle. I got it working :).

Comment: Adding the bug ticket from jqueryui for reference: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4731

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could create a handler for the dialog's `open` event and blur the field in that:

```
$("#mydiv").dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { 
       $('#theinput').blur(); 
   }
});
```

I'd need to see more of your code to be any more specific though.